# Linker command failed with exit code 1 cocoapods above 1.12.1

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

I have a react native project with a large number of cocoapods dependencies. I am currently on RN 0.73.5 and xcode 15.2 but I have seen this issue on previous versions as well. I am using cocoapods 1.12.1. If I try to update to any cocoapods version above this I get a build error `Linker command failed with exit code 1` and as far as I can tell none of my pods are getting linked. I am not changing anything else just bumping the cocoapods version. I imagine it is something specific with my environment and the specific set of pods I am using but I was wondering if anyone else had faced this issue and had managed to solve it. Many thanks.